# Whenever I install my Android App onto an android device...I cant launch it

Tags: android, google-play

Here is the market link:

https://market.android.com/details?id=processing.android.test.e1v1_0

Im not sure whats causing the problem but I tried both my HTC desire S and my galaxy tab and on both it shows as an installed package but the app icon doesn't appear.

anyone have any ideas? cheers

Heres the manifest!

Ok!

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="processing.android.test.e1v1_0" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
  <application android:label="E1V1_0" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".E1V1_0">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Yeah its a property in the manifest.  You have to make your app launchable.  Show us what yours looks like

Comment: The manifest is in the description now! :)

Comment: Do you see any problem with it?

Comment: This is just a guess, but it seems that the <application> element is missing the "android:name" attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I fixed this problem now:

heres how my manifest looks now...compiles properly with no errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="" android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="1.2.3">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" />
<application android:label="" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true">
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
 </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 </application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION"/>
 </manifest>
```